# Is it possible to extend Entity Framework to add new database query types?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

Would it be possible for me to extend EntityFramework (v6 for example) to add support for a new SQL function that EF currently doesn't support by possibly writing extensions onto the library. We are using MSSQL and don't need cross-db capabilities. We are calling a method in C# that string builds a SQL statement, then calls `ExecuteSqlCommand()` to execute it. This obviously is very ugly and I was wondering if it was possible to extend EF to add a whole new query ability such as `MERGE`.

We would need the entire LINQ query to generate an `IQueryable` like EF does and defer execution until needed just like for example `Context.MyCollection.Where(x => x.Num == 6).Select(x => x.ID)` doesn't get executed until actually needing the values. For instance like when calling `.ToList()`

As a side question, if I was able to extend EF to add this ability, would it even be possible to extend the LINQ query language as well. Example:

```
from s in Context.Schools
where s.District.DistrictName == "District 5"
merge os in Context.OtherSchools using (os.SchoolID == s.SchoolID) into m
when matched Context.OtherSchools.Update(s)
when not matched Context.OtherSchools.Add(s)
select m.inserted.id
```

Or something like that... I know that many of those don't exist, but I was wondering is it even *possible* to extend linq to add keywords to it? If not is it even *possible* to extend EF to add new features like implementation of SQL `MERGE` or others to the *lambda style*? And if it *is* possible, where would one even begin looking to add this functionality?

Comment: I would think you'd just implement the SQL commands in an Extension Method against IQueryable.

Comment: @novaterata that would make sense, and essentially what I am trying to do. Would this work with EF? Do you know of an example of an extension to IQueryable that works with EF that I could look at and learn from?

Comment: Check out EF 6 own extensions methods  https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/QueryableExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it seems nobody has answered yet.

It would not be possible to extend Linq the language itself. That is built into the C# compiler, and I do not think that it is extensible. I.e., you cannot introduce the `merge` keyword there.

As for extending the query provider for EF itself I'm unsure, but that's what I'm looking for myself. This would mean you could query using method syntax instead of Linq.

There are [some hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/providers/provider-model) about being able to register "services", but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually implement a derived query provider or something that would achieve translating new expression nodes into SQL while still using the existing provider implementation for everything else..

So far, I'd say it's not possible with EF6 (and if it is I'd say it's not well documented and no-man's land).